# scp no such file

Tags: terminal, scp

I'm on mac osx getting a file from a remote server. I run the following command:

```
scp remoteusername@remotehostip:/home/username/file.tar ./Users/localusername/Documents/specialdir
```

I get the response

```
scp: /home/username/file.tar: no such file or directory
```

However when I ssh into the remote host and run

```
cd /home/username
ls
```

file.tar is displayed. I have full read/write permissions for the directory/files. This is run in a new terminal (ie I am not already logged in via ssh to the remote host) What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

I worked around it using the * wildcard..although I'm still not sure what the root issue is/was.

Comment: You point that you use remoteusername to connect and then trying to get file from directory /home/username. Is it the same user or different users?

Comment: Are you logging in as the same user that you're SCPing with?

Comment: @Serge yes it's the same user.

Comment: did you try this: `scp remoteusername@remotehostip:file.tar ./Users/localusername/Documents/specialdir` ?

Comment: @Serge I did and I get the same error message

Comment: Did you copy that command or did you retype it? Because almost every time I get that error I forgot the `:` after the remote host name. (In which case it looks for a file in localhost, which is not there, and displays the no such file of directory message).

Comment: @Hennes I can confirm that the : is present in my command

Comment: Any interesting chars in the filename? (I am thinking of things like `*`'s which need to be escaped with \\*. Or an ampersand?  Does the user have read rights on the directory? (I would presume yes, since most users are allowed to read in their homedirs). - Just guessing here.

Comment: @Hennes all lowercase chars..

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and used * wildcard so it would work.  My file name has dashes in it, such as my-file-2015-01-01.zip, so perhaps that I why I needed to use *.zip